# Facebook not working in all browsers in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, browser

I can't load [facebook](http://facebook.com) in all of my browsers in Ubuntu 14.04 I don't know where the problem occurs. I already changed `IPv4` to `8.8.8.8` but still doesn't work. And also I could access on facebook only the first time that I used incognito mode then no more. I can also `ping facebook.com` and it works fine.

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: @Lucio Nothing it's just keep on loading.

Comment: @Lucio I got this error now `Unable to access the network`. Only when I browse facebook.com

Comment: Are you browsing trough a proxy? Other machines in your network can access facebook?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza strange

Comment: @Kriev I guess so. And yes you can browse facebook through mobile

Comment: Open terminal and type curl -i http://www.facebook.com and send us the output

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, it has to be solved with MTU size of Ethernet. Follow these steps:

1. Open up System Settings.
2. Go to Network in the Hardware section.
3. Select Wired in the list (which is active connection in my case, maybe another in your case).
4. Click Options button in the bottom of the right side window.
5. In the Ethernet tab, modify the MTU size to 1460 and click Save.

If it doesn't solve the issue, modify the MTU to other sizes between 1400 and 1500.

Again if the issue persists, modify DNS servers in your modem.

Answer (score 1):

Open Nautilus

Press Ctrl+H.  It will show hidden files and directories.

Find .mozilla or .chromium (any other browser you have) directory. It stores configuration files for the browser. Delete this folder.

After that try entering facebook.com. It should help.

**(Note that deleting this folder will erase all custom settings you have made like password, extensions,etc. and will make browser as it is in new installation)**

Also check if facebook is not blocked in your computer. Type sudo gedit /etc/hosts.Scroll through the lines of text in the file until you find the line that contains the text "facebook.com." If you can't find this line then that's not the problem.Delete the entire line, including the "127.0.0.1" at the beginning. Save the file.http://science.opposingviews.com/unblock-facebook-ubuntu-23437.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am having the same problem. I cannot get Facebook to load in any of my browsers on either of my ubuntu machines.

What I have tried. Changing DNS servers on the router and the ubuntu machines, resetting and configuring the router, power cycling the cable modem,clearing all browsing data, and disabling ufw. Nothing fixes the issue.

My Windows 7 machines load Facebook with no issues.

Comment: @Muzaffar, deleting the .mozilla file didn't help in my case.

Comment: @Perumal93, I think your MTU suggestion did the trick. I don't want to jinx it, but Facebook is now loading properly in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working on Ubuntu 14.04- Muzzafar's solution above worked a treat for me, but then you do lose your custom settings in chromium.

Downloading the chrome browser for linux direct from google means that you can then use that for browsing when custom settings are useful or necessary. But there are probably disadvantages with this app- which is not in the official Ubuntu repository (it is in the Mint repository though I think).